# Swift: json data numbers are behaving differently

Tags: ios, swift

I have a IOS project which is developed in Swift. In application the data is received from webservices. I have tested in our beta server and all is fine. But when I moved my webservices to our live server the id's and numbers are not converted as integers instead they are treated as strings. The following is the json data example coming from the server:

```
id = 16737;
        image = "";
        "last_name" = "Test";
        "organizer_id" = 75;
        "show_home" = 0;
        status = 1;
```

in the above data the numbers are treated as Strings when the data comes from the live server and treated as Int when the data comes from beta server, and the data format is same on both servers.
Following is the swift code I am using for Int and string columns
For Integers:

```
if let organizer_id = dict["organizer_id"]! as? Int
                    {
                        Utilities.sharedInstance.setDataToUserDefaults(KEY_ORGANIZER_ID, value: String(organizer_id))
                    }
```

For String:

```
if let email = dict["email"]! as? String
                    {
                        Utilities.sharedInstance.setDataToUserDefaults(KEY_USER_EMAIL, value: email)
                    }
```

But when comes from live server it bypass the integer condition and do not save that data which is very irritating. What am I doing wrong, and what is the proper way of doing this, so that I will not face this problem in future?

Comment: As you already said the only thing that changes is the server, so there must be a problem. They are treated as strings because they are sent as strings. You can of course convert them to int but then it won't work when sent as Int.

Comment: I'd recommend to compare the PHP versions and the `json_encode` function on both servers. Maybe the PHP versions are different and/or the attribute to consider numeric strings as numbers. And remove the exclamation marks in both optional bindings lines

Comment: Both servers have the same PHP versions and both json_encode functions returns the same output when seen by var_dump method of php

Comment: Please print the original JSON coming from the server, not the output of some logging command. We have no idea if the 75 for example is a number or a string.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution on SO you just need to do in PHP while sending json data:

```
json_encode($array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

This flag will ensure that the numeric values will be sent as Integers instead of string. Thankyou again for your comments.